# Python: Unable to return gift with nested function

Tags: python

```
def hypo(a,b):
    def square(x): return x*x;
    return math.sqrt(square(a) + square(b));
def secondfunction():
     result = hypo(1,2);
     print(result);
```

I am trying to learn Python myself but unable to understand what is wrong?

Expected Result something like this 2.23606797749979

Comment: What is the problem that you&#39;re facing? If you add `import math` this works for me. Side note, in python, `;` are not necessary

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using a lambda:

```
import math

def hypo(a,b):
    square = lambda x: x * x
    return math.sqrt(square(a) + square(b))

def secondfunction():
     result = hypo(1, 2)
     print(result)

secondfunction()
```

Output:

```
2.23606797749979
```

Also, you don't need semicolons in Python, unless you want to make a winky-face ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `secondfunction()` to get the result

```
def hypo(a,b):
    return (a ** 2 + b ** 2) ** 0.5

def secondfunction():
     print(hypo(1,2))

secondfunction()
```

**Output:**

```
2.23606797749979
```

Comment: You also need to `import math` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
def hypo(a,b):
    def square(x):
        return x*x
    return math.sqrt(square(a) + square(b))
def secondfunction():
    result = hypo(1,2)
    print(result)

secondfunction()
```

or if you execute it from a script you can add at the end

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    secondfunction()
```

Output

```
2.23606797749979
```